# Highlighting onclick menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble keeping the 'current' link highlighted. The links are simply layed out like:

**Home | About | Jordon**

For example, once a user clicks on a link, that particular link will get highlighted.

I've tried using this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#menu li a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#menu li a").addClass("current").not(this).removeClass("current");
}); 
});
```

HTML

> ```
>   <div class="main">
>         <div id="menu">
>             <ul>
>                 <li><a onclick="window.location='index.action'" href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
>                 <li><a onclick="window.location='about.action?c=azuki'" href="#">About</a></li>
>                 <li><a onclick="window.location='about.action?c=jordon'" href="#">Jordon</a></li>
>                 <li>                </ul>           </div>
>                 </div>
> ```

CSS

> #menu li a.current {color:#3558b0}

Comment: If you would just use the `href` attribute you could look at using `:active` pseudo-class. (I see no reason to use `onclick="window.location"` when `href` is the exact same thing.)

Comment: I agree with @BradChristie.  Also, will the click event wired up in the jQuery code even run, or will the onclick attribute from the a redirect to the new page before bubbling to the jQuery click event?  If so, his jQuery click event code will never get run.

Comment: writing inline javascript is a crime in 2012.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#menu').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
$('#menu a').removeClass( 'current' );
$(this).addClass( 'current' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

I am using onclick to directly open the #azuki and #jordon ui-tabs (jquery)  within the about page.

Comment: @user1652920 Please can you remember to accept my answer by ticking it (so future viewers know it is the right one) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Element-level events are going to fire before jQuery (or any other library that's attached). Your problem is execution order.

Try this for starters:

```
<div id="menu">
  <a onclick="alert('First');">Helllo, World!</a>
</div>

$('a').on('click',function(e){
  alert('Second');
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

`onclick` fires and sets the `window.location` before jQuery has a chance to `preventDefault()`/cancel the event. My advice is to use `href` as it was intended and make your jQuery adjustments atop HTML.

Rule of thumb: Keep Markup for markup and scripting for scripting; don't mix. (avoid using the `onclick` attribute for example).

If you follow that rule, you're backwards compatible for older browsers/those with JavaScript disabled while still offering extended functionality for newer ones. Chances are you'll also save bandwidth by allowing cached functionality now instead of repeated tasks embedded in every tag.

With that being said, try this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.action" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.action?c=azuki">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.action?c=jordon">Jordon</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#menu a').on('click',function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('current');
        $this.addClass('current');
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

I'm still not sure what you're hoping to accomplish though because after `window.location` loads any class you have applied will be moot on the next page visit (unless you're using AJAX). You can, however, reference `$this.prop('href')` though and use it in the click event for whatever you may need to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using onclick to directly open the #azuki and #jordon tabs (ui jquery) within the about page. If I get rid of onclick and use href, I cant open the about.action?c=azuki tab or about.action?c=jordon tab within the about page.

Comment: @user1652920: No need, jQueryUI-Tabs [already can do this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html). It will look at the `href` attribute and load it for you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. using onclick, I am able to click and load the ui-tabs properly. However, I cannot get the menu link to be highlighted.

Comment: @user1652920: If you're using jQuery tabs, why can't use add `#menu ui-state-active a { color: 3558b0; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Though your  JQuery code is valid, but your markup is not proper. I have put the following working demo for you:

[JsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/Sp82g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get rid of `onclick` (i.e. using `href`) then you can do this with **CSS ONLY**. You dont require jQuery code. See here:

CSS:

```
#menu li a.current {color:#3558b0}

#menu li a:active,
#menu li a:focus{
 color:#fff;
background-color:red;   
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="main">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a  href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Jordon</a></li>
                <li>                </ul>           </div>
                </div>
```

Heres a jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fUL3w/10/

Comment: Thanks. This works if I get rid of onclick; however, in order for about.action?c=azuki and about.action?c=jordon to load correctly, I have to use onclick.

about.action?c=jordon and about.action?c=azuki are tabs (ui jquery) within the about page.